# Low call volume on Nexus 5 Lollipop

Tags: nexus-5, 5.0-lollipop, volume

After upgrading my Nexus 5 to Android Lollipop, the volume in call is extremely low. I've compared it to my girlfriend's exact same Nexus and she hasn't got any problems. Is there a solution to this? I searched everywhere and couldn't find a solution.

The volume was perfectly fine before the update.

Answer (score -1):

Backup your data and reset the phone.

I had the exact same problem, the way I fixed it is by doing a factory reset. To nail down the problem, I booted up the phone into safe mode (Long press the 'Power Off' on your power menu). There, it was better, so I decided to wipe my phone and recover my data afterwards using TWRP. Also, you should note that 5.0.1 sort of improved the speakers - both of them, the earpiece and the actual speaker.

Comment: Without any explanation about possible cause of the issue, I'd say this is the last thing OP should do though.

Comment: I agree with Andrew, though I can see a possible explanation (many users reported issues following the LP upgrade, which were fixed by a factory-reset). When throwing in such an action, you should always explain the background – as backup and restore are a time-consuming task most times.